# How can I group a sorted pandas.Series?

Tags: python, pandas

Given a sorted *pandas.Series* (or just a list) object I want to create groups (e.g., lists or *pandas.Series*) such that the difference between adjacent elements in the group is less than some threshold, e.g.:

```
THRESHOLD = 2
sorted_list = [1, 2, 10, 15, 16, 17, 20, 21]
# ...
result = [[1, 2], [10], [15, 16, 17], [20, 21]]
```

Comment: How would you group if you have `[1, 2, 3, 4,..]`?

Comment: @kerwei I think the threshold is clear. If he has your list, it will be grouped into one sublist.

Comment: @Yusufsn Yes, you're right. Re-read his statement and it makes sense now. Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `diff` and `cumsum` to mark groups, then use `groupby`:

```
s = pd.Series(sorted_list)
s.groupby(s.diff().gt(THRESHOLD).cumsum()).apply(list).tolist()
# [[1, 2], [10], [15, 16, 17], [20, 21]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using

```
s = pd.Series(sorted_list)

[y.tolist() for x , y in s.groupby(s.diff().gt(THRESHOLD).cumsum())]
Out[167]: [[1, 2], [10], [15, 16, 17], [20, 21]]
```